# Deleted answer (virus warning)

Tags: discussion, delete

I'm sorry, but I don't understand why you deleted my answer on the following topic:

[How to change the theme of Windows 8 to the classic theme?](https://superuser.com/questions/783101/how-to-change-the-theme-of-windows-8-to-the-classic-theme)

It was just about to warn everyone, that a file is NOT what it supposed to be, and that it contains a virus. Please, undo the deletion ASAP. My message was intended to help others to maintain their safety on the net!

Comment: The reason is this is a Q and A site, not a forum. The first post is the question, others are the answers. If you look at your deleted question, you'll see the comment `This does not provide an answer to the question.` If you have an additional question, then simply post a new question :)

Comment: The answer was deleted because it wasn't a answer but a comment, its not going to be undeleted, for that treason.  If the current answer links to a malicious file, report it, and THAT answer will be deleted.

Comment: I added "Warning: http://bertrand.deo.free.fr/TEMP/w8classic.zip is triggering malware alerts. See https://www.virustotal.com/en/url/1965ec7532496c7389505946db8bfdf785254c002cbecd3113805cb8d23cf2a1/analysis/ and https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/d2e2622d6a07e8fdc5144d660c85efd4d7363f6db0e88afa540a7227c7141c3b/analysis/1444792354/ for more information. Use this file with caution." to the answer.

Comment: Note that this could well be a false positive, `ClassicTheme.exe` (Portable Executable) is triggering the alert.

Answer (score 1):

We allow only answers in the answer section, no exceptions. Once you have sufficient reputation, you'll be able to comment everywhere and downvote bad answers.

A very important power that you get pretty early (15 reputation) is the ability to flag posts. If you're sure that an answer is malicious, flag it as needing moderator attention, and *fully explain the situation* and what you want done. If you're not so certain, you can ask about it in chat, which is open to anybody with 20 reputation or more.

There's also meta (right here!), which anybody with 5 reputation can participate in. It's perfectly acceptable to ask on meta for something to be done when you don't have sufficient privileges to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, Ben for giving me that important update on how things work on superuser. Something I simply didn't know about / didn't understand completely, but I do now and will act accordingly, I mean I will ask someone who has higher reputation or is a moderator (of course including full explanation of the problem, as you said). However on most of the forums out there, it is more simple to report things that look malicious. But sorry & nevermind. :-)